# Send Textbox Data to a specific row/cell in a Worksheet based on the Value of a ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I built a userform that captures data on how long it takes a worker to do a job.

I created a second form to lookup the reference and enter the time he/she finished the job.

I can send all data from the first form to the worksheet 'Tracker' and also lookup the 'Job Reference' to populate the data on the second userform. I cannot however send the 'End Time' to the row that relates to the 'Job Reference' identifier.

I tried using the same code I used to find an empty row and insert data in the first form, but it enters the end time in the next empty row.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

endTimeTxt.Value = Time

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Defines worksheet and Database Var
Dim findRng As Range
Dim lookup As String
lookup = Trim(Application.InputBox("What ID do you want to find?"))
Set findRng = Range("G5:G1000").Find(what:=lookup)

If Not findRng Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "The row to use is: " & findRng.Row
Else
    MsgBox (lookup & "was not found in column A!")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21")
    Me.jobRefCbo.List = xRg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub jobRefCbo_Change()

    'Formatting Issue
    jobCloseFrm.date2Txt.Value = Format(Range("W1").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Me.nameTxt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21"), 2, False)
        Me.jobDesc2Txt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21"), 3, False)
        'Me.date2Txt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21"), 4, False)
        Me.month2Txt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21"), 5, False)
        Me.timeOnJobTxt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21"), 6, False)
        Me.StatusTxt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21"), 7, False)
        Me.startTime2Txt.Value = Format(CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I2:P21"), 8, False)), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

End Sub
```

I was at the point of trying code I googled which is why the code to send the Time End doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Please share the code...

Comment: Which cell should the End Time go in?

Comment: It should look up the Job Ref Row and then enter it in the 9th Column along. I essentially want to send it to the row the Job Ref is in but I only know how to send to empty rows.

Comment: So:

Take the Value of the ComboBox, look up Column A and find it, then insert the TextBox Value into the 9th Column in that specific row

Comment: You can use `Find` to find the combobox in column A (similar to code in the button click code) and then the column I will be `cells(findvariable.row,9)`.

Comment: This sounds excellent, how would that look if I was to type it into the Click event. Thanks again for contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, something like this

```
'in click event

Dim findRng As Range

Set findRng = Range("A5:A1000").Find(what:=Me.combobox1.Value) 'insert name of combobox here

If Not findRng Is Nothing Then
    Cells(findRng.Row, 9).Value = Me.textbox1.Value            'insert name of textbox here
End If
```